# Datepicker datetime format issue. behaviour changes if change the local system date format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in MVC3 and doing a assessment kind of work for my company. Today, I am stuck with date format in MVC3.

I have a model class with following methods

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Date Of Joining")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
public DateTime? DOJ { get; set; }
```

In my view I called a jquery inbuilt function Datepicker

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#DOB").datepicker({
                                 changeMonth: true,
                                 changeYear: true,
                                 yearRange: "1942:2099",
                                 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
                            });
        $("#DOJ").datepicker({
                                 changeMonth: true,
                                 changeYear: true,
                                 yearRange: "2010:2099",
                                 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
                            });
    });
</script>
```

This code is working fine if my local system date format in "dd-mm-yyyy" format but start throwing error if I change the date format in any other format in my local system.

Here my question is, how can I make it in Universal date time format so that it will not throw error after deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like issue is related with culture settings. I had a similar issue with Date format and i resolved it by adding these line in web.config's `<system.web>` section

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

Hope it helps!!